# SecurityFilterChain - http.authorizeHttpRequests() not working. localhost redirected you too many times

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Since `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated I am trying to replace `configure(HttpSecurity http)` with `SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http)`. I've tried to piece together below code but it is not working and is giving `localhost redirected you too many times` error on chrome but is not showing any error in console. I've even cleared cookies as suggested but it still isn't working.

**AppSecurityConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
public class AppSecurityConfig {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder()); 
        
        return provider;
    }
    
    //Trying to replace configure(HttpSecurity http) method
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().invalidateHttpSession(true)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success").permitAll();

        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

`.authorizeRequests()` is deprecated so I am using `.authorizeHttpRequests()`.
Below SS is output from chrome:
[Output error from chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0raf.png)

**HomeComtroller.java**

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "home.jsp";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login.jsp";
    }
    @RequestMapping("/logout-success")
    public String logoutPage() {
        return "logout.jsp";
    }
}
```

**login.jsp**

```
<body>
    <h1>Login</h1>
    ${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}
    <form action="login" method="post">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>User:</td>
                <td><input type='text' name='username' value='' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Password:</td>
                <td><input type="password" name='password' /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" name='submit' value='submit' /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.loginPage()` javadoc says this:

`...login page to redirect to if authentication is required...`

With your endpoint `/login` served by controller, you enter redirects cycle. You can try next:

1. Create `MvcConfig` class (customize it due to your own rules):

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

2. Delete yor `/login` endpoint from controller.
3. Test new configuration.

Hope it helps, feel free to give feedback for my answer.

Comment: Has this solved?

Comment: Hello, @HasankaSapumal! My answer was not marked as correct or even upvoted, though I think it's working correctly. Feel free to ask any help on that codepiece)